# TomEE is not generating webservice for @WebService EJB

Tags: java, web-services, ejb-3.0, ejb-3.1

I am trying to run examples provided at TomEE example website : https://tomee.apache.org/examples-trunk/simple-webservice/README.html. But when I start the application with TomEE, I am not able to hit the wsdl URL. It doesn't find the resource. In console also, I can't see the webservice entry.
Can anyone please help with what could be wrong with my approach?

Answer (score 0):

This is a jar? Set packaging to war and deploy the war. Wsdl will be accessible adding ?_wsdl to the logged url during startup.

Comment: Thanks Romain for addressing the issue. I figured out that I was not making use of TomeePlus or Plume and thats why when I tried starting the server, the @WebService went unnoticed by the server and no web service was created.